# Google Play inapp Review API: does it work in 'Open Testing'?

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services, google-play-console, google-play-developer-api

It seems that no [Google Play inapp review alert](https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/in-app-review#integrate_in-app_reviews_in_your_app) is displayed to the users when they download the app from the store in 'open testing'.

Is this observation correct?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation for testing the review manager found [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/in-app-review/test), it's only available when using internal app sharing or an internal test track, so I'm cautiously writing this as an answer to say:

No, it most likely won't be available in open testing, at least if we're going by the strict definition of what's written in the documentation

Comment: It is written 'Your app doesn't have to be published to test, but your app's applicationID must be available at least in the internal testing track.' So I understand that it should work in Open Testing as Open Testing is a mode 'more open' than 'internal test tracking'. But in real life, it seems that the users don't see the Google rating alert when they download in Open testing. So I would like to have a 100% reliable answer as I wonder if there is something wrong in my implementation. Thanks.

Comment: i completely understand, having worked with this recently i can confirm that internal app sharing does work like they have documented, so it definitely is possible to get the dialog to show without having it as a production release, which leads me to believe that it will only work for those 2 methods and potentially not for the rest, even in your comment `must be available at least in the internal testing track.` leads me to believe that it has to be on internal, while it might make sense for it to work in open testing, that just might not be the case here